# Analyzing crash dump (NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ)

Tags: java, crash-dumps

My application is crashing from time to time. Looking at windows crash dump, the following seems interesting:

```
ExceptionAddress: 000000006abc0608 (jvm!JVM_ResolveClass+0x000000000001d6b8)  
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)  
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ  
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.  
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_c0000005_jvm.dll!JVM_ResolveClass  
BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_jvm!JVM_ResolveClass+1d6b8
```

Can you please assist with how should I analyze it? How can I tell if it's something in my application code or in the JVM code?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem a few years ago, and after I had changed my RAM, it disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Java program should *not* be able to crash the JVM (I assume you're not using JNI or similar).

I would upgrade your JVM and try a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a JVM issue. I would recommend trying your application on another computer just to be sure. Make sure you're using the latest version of Java as well.